# Null Results From TIMESTAMPDIFF in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2, timestampdiff

I am calculating a TIMESTAMPDIFF from timestamps that can have a fairly large range of time intervals between them, from a few tenths of a second to 60+mins. Since the DB2 TIMESTAMPDIFF() function in DB2 returns an integer as a result, I am using microseconds as my numeric interval expression. TIMESTAMPDIFF DB2 documentation states:

> Microseconds (the absolute value of the duration must be less than 3547.483648)

This equates to approximately ~59 minutes - so any interval over this amount returns as a null value which is the issue I'm trying to address.

Sample queries/timestamps I'm working with in the data:

```
select timestampdiff(1, char(timestamp('2022-09-12 14:30:40.444896') - timestamp('2022-09-12 14:30:40.115789'))) from sysibm.SYSDUMMY1

select timestampdiff(1, char(timestamp('2022-09-12 15:59:14.548636') - timestamp('2022-09-12 14:56:10.791140'))) from sysibm.SYSDUMMY1
```

The second query above is an example that returns a null value as the result exceeds the maximum result interval limit. I am pigeon-holed into using microseconds as my interval as results less than 1 whole second are still valid.

Are there any methods of working around this limit to return results exceeding the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you subtract dates or timestamps, you end up with a duration..

A duration is a number formatted as `yyyymmddhhmmss.zzzzzzzzzzzz`.
From the manual:

> ```
> A timestamp duration represents a number of years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, and
> fractional seconds, expressed as a DECIMAL(14+s,s) number, where s is the number of digits of
> fractional seconds ranging from 0 to 12. To be properly interpreted, the number must have the format
> yyyymmddhhmmss.zzzzzzzzzzzz, where yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm, ss, and zzzzzzzzzzzz represent,
> respectively, the number of years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fractional seconds. The
> result of subtracting one timestamp value from another is a timestamp duration with scale that
> matches the maximum timestamp precision of the timestamp operands.
> ```

```
select timestamp('2022-09-12 15:59:14.548636') - timestamp('2022-09-12 14:56:10.791140') from sysibm.SYSDUMMY1;
```

returns `10303.757496`

And is read as 1 hour, 3 minutes, 3.757496 seconds

So if you wanted to, you can do the math yourself.  Better yet build your own UDF that returns a big integer or even larger as a decimal value.

Comment: "Keep it simple stupid" to my self right now. Tests seem to pass on this simple solution, use of timestampdiff() does not seem to be needed at all for this use-case. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  A, B
, (
    (DAYS (A) - DAYS (B)) * DEC (86400, 31)
  + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS (A) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS (B)
  ) * 1000
  + (MICROSECOND (A) - MICROSECOND (B)) / 1000
  AS DIFF_MS
FROM 
(
  VALUES
  (timestamp('2022-09-12 14:30:40.444896'), timestamp('2022-09-12 14:30:40.115789'))
, (timestamp('2022-09-12 15:59:14.548636'), timestamp('2022-09-12 14:56:10.791140'))
) T (A, B)
```

| A | B | DIFF_MS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-12 14:30:40.444896 | 2022-09-12 14:30:40.115789 | 329 |
| 2022-09-12 15:59:14.548636 | 2022-09-12 14:56:10.791140 | 3783758 |

**Update**
Just in case. You should be familiar with `TIMESTAMPDIFF` specific.
It works on timestamp DURATIONs (in the `yyyymmddhhmmss.zzzzzzzzzzzz` format, but I've truncated the `z's` part) and may produce quite a "surprising" result, if the difference is more than 1 month.

```
SELECT 
  DATE (A) AS A, DATE (B) AS B
, DAYS (B) - DAYS (A) AS DIFF_REAL
, TIMESTAMPDIFF (16, CHAR (B - A)) AS DIFF_TS
, INT (CHAR (B - A)) AS DURATION
, (DAYS (B) - DAYS (A)) * 86400 AS DIFF_REAL_SEC
, TIMESTAMPDIFF (2, CHAR (B - A)) AS DIFF_TS_SEC
FROM 
(
  VALUES 
  ('2022-01-01'::TIMESTAMP, '2022-02-01'::TIMESTAMP)
, ('2022-01-31'::TIMESTAMP, '2022-03-01'::TIMESTAMP)
, ('2022-02-01'::TIMESTAMP, '2022-03-01'::TIMESTAMP)
, ('2022-02-01'::TIMESTAMP, '2022-02-28'::TIMESTAMP)
) T (A, B)
```

| A | B | DIFF_REAL | DIFF_TS | DURATION | DIFF_REAL_SEC | DIFF_TS_SEC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 31 | 30 | 1,00,00,00,00 | 2 678 400 | 2 592 000 |
| 2022-01-31 | 2022-03-01 | 29 | 31 | 1,01,00,00,00 | 2 505 600 | 2 678 400 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-03-01 | 28 | 30 | 1,00,00,00,00 | 2 419 200 | 2 592 000 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 | 27 | 27 | 27,00,00,00 | 2 332 800 | 2 332 800 |

So, in short: don't use DURATIONs and TIMESTAMPDIFF, if you want to calculate the difference between 2 timestamps in days, hours, minutes, etc., if the difference is more than 1 month.